# When the 'speedy trial' amendment was written, how long did trials usually take?

Tags: united-states, law, us-constitution

The Sixth Amendment to the United States Constitution promises "the right to a speedy and public trial," to prevent the accused from being held without a conviction for a long pretrial period. What would have been considered a reasonable length of time for a trial in the early United States at the time this amendment was written?

Also, how long did appeals and civil cases take?

Comment: Can you let us know where you have looked already so that folks here don't duplicate your research?

Comment: "Speedy" does not mean the time that a trial takes, but the time between arrest and trial.

Comment: Exactly.  The amendment was about preventing people from being locked up for years "awaiting" trial.

Comment: Whether this wins the prize for "most ignored amendment" is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It looks like [the book](https://books.google.com/books?id=rG4KI18gEmEC) *The Right to a Speedy and Public Trial: A Reference Guide to the United States Constitution* may address this question around pp.163-166, but I've run out of Google preview pages.

Comment: @Gort the Robot: Having the right to something does not mean that you need to exercise that right.  It's often the defense that wants to delay a trial, in order to have time to build a case.  (The prosecution probably has done most of their work before an arrest.)